# initWebApplicationContext Error creating bean with name primefaces

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces

I have the following error, I do not understand because in another classes if make me the beans. I wrote the next code. app-config.xml EmpresaManagebBean.java.

**Error**

```
Información: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@12839c7: defining beans [empresasController,empresasDAOImpl,empresaMB,empresasServiceImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,propertyConfigurer,myDataSource,mySessionFactory,transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
nov 04, 2014 2:01:51 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
Grave: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'empresaMB' defined in file [C:\Users\ProSyth\miJee2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\Apliconta2WebPrimefaces\WEB-INF\classes\com\atorresbr\springapp\EmpresasManagedBean.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.atorresbr.springapp.EmpresasManagedBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1007)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.atorresbr.springapp.EmpresasManagedBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1000)
    ... 22 more
```

**app-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components @Service @Repository to deploy as 
        beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.atorresbr.springapp" />

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

      <!-- Map simple view name such as "test" into /WEB-INF/test.jsp -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

  <!-- JDBC Data Source. It is assumed you have MySQL running on localhost port 3306 with
       username root and blank password. Change below if it's not the case -->

       <bean id="myDataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" 
        p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}" 
        p:validationQuery="${jdbc.validationQuery}" />
 <!--       
  <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pizzashop"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>
  </bean>   -->

  <!-- Hibernate Session Factory -->
  <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>com.atorresbr.springapp</value>
      </array>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
            </props>

    </property>
  </bean>

  <!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
  <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
  </bean>

  <!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
  <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
</beans>
```

**EmpresaManagedBean.java**

```
package com.atorresbr.springapp;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;



@ManagedBean("empresaMB")
@RequestScoped
public class EmpresasManagedBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    //@Autowired private EmpresasService empresasService;


    //Spring User Service is injected...
    @ManagedProperty(value="#{EmpresasService}")
    EmpresasService empresasService;



    List<Empresas> empresaList = empresasService.findAll();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace shows

`Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.atorresbr.springapp.EmpresasManagedBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`.

You got a NullPointerException in the constructor of EmpresasManagedBean.
Unfortunately you did not post the constructor, so I cant't help you there.

Comment: Sorry, where goes the constructor of EmpresasManagedBean? Thx.

Comment: The constructor is a specialised "method" of a java-class. It is used to instantiate (creating a object) of that class. Every class has at least one constructor. It typically looks like `public CLASSNAME(){}`, which would be the default-constructor. In your case public EmpresasManagedBean(){}. Parameters are allowed, so you can have multiple constructors. The Stacktrace should point you to the line number that contains the NullPointerException